# Custom garmin map have no name

Tags: bash, openstreetmap, basecamp, garmin

I created a Garmin map from my own OSM files (using JOSM and my own GPS records, no input from Openstreetmap).
The whole process run well, but I have just a little problem : when I load the final map to Basecamp, the name of this map is empty (blank).

Any idea ?

Here is the code. Before, some variables :

```
PREFIX=640000
ORIGINALNAME=$(echo ${PREFIX}00)
NAME=$(echo ${PREFIX}01)

ID_PUBLIC=64

DIR="/home/Carto"
GMAPIBUILDER="/Applications/Carto/gmapi-builder.py"
MKGMAP="/Applications/Carto/mkgmap/mkgmap.jar"
```

First, create img files from different layers

```
for f in $DIR/src/public/*.osm ; do
    g=$(basename $f .osm) ;
    d=$(dirname $f)

    java -Xmx2G -jar $MKGMAP \
    --transparent --add-pois-to-areas \
    --keep-going --draw-priority=$drawpriority \
    --description="[iero] "$g \
    --family-name="iero Congo" \
    --series-name="iero Congo" \
    --mapname=$NAME --family-id=$ID --product-id=$ID \
    --country-name=Congo --country-abbr=CG \
    --style-file=$DIR/styles --style=iero \
    --copyright-message="[iero.org] Congo $DATE" \
    --product-version=$VERSION \
    --latin1 --output-dir=$DIR/output/imgs/public $f 1> /dev/null; 

    cp $DIR/output/imgs/public/${NAME}.img $DIR/output/imgs/public/${NAME}.img

    let NAME++ ;
    let nbfiles++ ;
    let drawpriority++ ;
done
```

Next, concatenate those files in unique img file

```
java -jar $MKGMAP --tdbfile --gmapsupp $DIR/output/imgs/public/*.img \
    --keep-going \
    --style-file=$DIR/styles --style=iero \
    --family-name="iero Congo" \
    --series-name="iero Congo" \
    --description="[iero] Congo map" \
    --mapname=$ORIGINALNAME --family-id=${ID_PUBLIC} --product-id=${ID_PUBLIC} \
    --copyright-message="[iero.org] Congo $DATE" \
    --product-version=$VERSION \
    --output-dir=$DIR/output/gps/public 1> /dev/null;
```

Then, create gmapi files, ready for Basecamp :

```
python $GMAPIBUILDER -t $DIR/output/gps/public/osmmap.tdb -b $DIR/output/gps/public/osmmap.img -o $DIR/output/basecamp/mac/public $DIR/output/imgs/public/*.img
```

If you want to see the problem, final files can be downloaded in my website : http://www.iero.org/blog/2014/06/carte-du-congo/

Thanks !

Greg

Comment: What's actually empty? Is it a variable? And I would suggest placing your variables around quotes to prevent word splitting: e.g. `java -jar "$MKGMAP" ...`. If you see error messages when you run the script, mind posting them?

Comment: When I load the map in basecamp, the version is good, but the name is blank. I can still use the map by selecting the "empty map" in basecamp, but it's not very convenient. I have no error during the script. I will try to add some verbose mode.

Comment: Name of the map itself or of the POIs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done testing and only get the blank names with versions of mkgmap after they introduced the overview map feature. I built a map with r2585 and the name showed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will run my maps on r2585 !